# Which CAs offer EV SSL certs with multiple domain names?

Tags: ssl

I know Comodo does.
http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/addsupport/ssl-ev-mdc.html

Any others? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one appears to as well for an additional price per domain (like Comodo after 3):

http://www.globalsign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/unified-communications-ssl/

Answer (score 1):

Verisign does.  http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/subject-alternative-name-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Geotrust does. http://www.geotrust.com/ssl/extended-validation-ssl/ (up to 25 SAN). Notice that Versign, Thawte, and Geotrust are all the same company now: Symantec.